# DayJS: How to format a date like date-fns.formatISO9075 does in DayJS

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns, dayjs

I have a file that was using the [date-fns.formatISO9075](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/formatISO9075) from date-fns.

```
const dateFns = require('date-fns')

dateFns.formatISO9075(anniversaryDateLessThanCurrent)
```

We're moving to [day.js](https://day.js.org/)

But I am unclear how to replicate that?

I tried:

```
dayjs(anniversaryDateGreaterThanCurrent).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS')
```

But my test failed.

Any idea how to format that?

Comment: In what way did "… my test failed."? What did you expect? What did you get? What is the value of *anniversaryDateGreaterThanCurrent*?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [date-fns docs](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/formatISO9075), it appears that using the `formatISO9075` function without any options results in the following

```
// Represent 18 September 2019 in ISO 9075 format:
const result = formatISO9075(new Date(2019, 8, 18, 19, 0, 52))
//=> '2019-09-18 19:00:52'
```

This would correspond with the following formatting -- `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'`

Comparing this to the dayjs code that you posted,

```
dayjs(anniversaryDateGreaterThanCurrent).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS')
```

it's going to return milliseconds as well.

I would expect this to work as expected if you update the format string to

```
dayjs(anniversaryDateGreaterThanCurrent).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```